# Using Hixny web service for Query, Add etc

Tags: c#

Is Anyone aware of using Hixny web service "https://integration.hixny.com/csp/public/hsbus/EnsLib.IHE.PIXv3.Manager.Services.cls" for Query,Add etc.

I Tried connecting to hixny endpoints by passing the sample XML and Certificate but it is not working. Getting Error "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the request to hixny requires valid SAML headers i.e UserName and UserOrganization.

Error occured as I was passing incorrect values.